# Group a Spark df by one column and split the result of one column into multiple columns - Pivoting and selective merging

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pandas-groupby

I have the following spark df

Please note that you may run this locally only if you already install spark by running the following command. Otherwise replicate the issue on a Databricks cluster which will initialize a spark context automatically.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark =  SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
```

```py
spark_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['867', '430', '658', '157', '521', '867', '430', '867'],
                                'Probability':[0.12, 0.72, 0.32, 0.83, 0.12, 0.49, 0.14, 0.12], 
                                'RAG': ['G', 'R', 'A', 'R', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'G'],
                                'Timestamp': ['2020-07-01 17-49-32', '2020-07-01 17-49-32', '2020-07-01 17-49-32', '2020-07-01 17-49-32', '2020-07-01 17-49-32', '2020-07-01 16-45-32', '2020-07-01 16-45-32', '2020-07-01 15-45-32']})
spark_dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(spark_dataframe)
```

Now I want to group this spark dataframe by 'id' and count the values of the 'RAG' column splitting them into different columns. So get something like this,

```
+---+--------------------+-------------+------------+
| id||G(count)|A(count)|R(count)|Timestamp(max)     |
+---+--------------------+-------------+------------+
|867|        2|       1|       0|2020-07-01 17-49-32|
|430|        1|       0|       1|2020-07-01 17-49-32|
|658|        0|       1|       0|2020-07-01 17-49-32|
|157|        0|       0|       1|2020-07-01 17-49-32|
|521|        1|       0|       0|2020-07-01 17-49-32|
+---+--------------------+-------------+------------+
```

Based on the Spark dataframe above create a list of dictionaries like:

```py
final_list=[]
map_dictionary={"R":0.6, "A":0.3, "G":0.1}

final_list=[{"id": "867", "RAG": "G", "Timestamp": "2020-07-01 17-49-32"}, #because for the id 867 the G column had 2 counts greater than the rest A, R column values on the same row.
 {"id": "430", "RAG": "R", "Timestamp": "2020-07-01 17-49-32"} #because G and R had 1 occurrence but R has greater weight based on the map dictionary,...
] #length of the list is equal to 5 since five are the unique rows of the spark df above.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can group and pivot them.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
#%%
tst = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(867,0.12,'G','2020-07-01 17-49-32'),(430,0.72,'R','2020-07-01 17-49-32'),(658,0.32,'A','2020-07-01 17-49-32'),\
                                              (157,0.83,'R','2020-07-01 17-49-32'),(521,0.12,'G','2020-07-01 17-49-32'),(867,0.49,'A','2020-07-01 16-45-32'),
                                              (430,0.14,'G','2020-07-01 16-45-32'),(867,0.12,'G','2020-07-01 16-45-32')],
                                               schema=['id','Probability','RAG','Timestamp'])
tst1 = tst.groupby('id').pivot('RAG').agg(F.count('Probability').alias('count'),F.max('Timestamp').alias('time_stamp'))
# there will be one time stamp per value of 'RAG'. The below code will find maximum among them
ts_coln = [F.col(x) for x in tst1.columns if 'time_stamp' in x]

tst2 = tst1.withColumn('max_ts',F.greatest(*ts_coln))
```

Results:

+---+-------+-------------------+-------+-------------------+-------+------------

```
-------+-------------------+
| id|A_count|       A_time_stamp|G_count|       G_time_stamp|R_count|       R_time_stamp|             max_ts|
+---+-------+-------------------+-------+-------------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|658|      1|2020-07-01 17-49-32|      0|               null|      0|               null|2020-07-01 17-49-32|
|430|      0|               null|      1|2020-07-01 16-45-32|      1|2020-07-01 17-49-32|2020-07-01 17-49-32|
|521|      0|               null|      1|2020-07-01 17-49-32|      0|               null|2020-07-01 17-49-32|
|157|      0|               null|      0|               null|      1|2020-07-01 17-49-32|2020-07-01 17-49-32|
|867|      1|2020-07-01 16-45-32|      2|2020-07-01 17-49-32|      0|               null|2020-07-01 17-49-32|
+---+-------+-------------------+-------+-------------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Finally, you can drop the irrelevant columns

Comment: Raghu Thank you for the answer, it works successfully and yields the appropriate results. Do you have any input on the creation of the final list with dictionaries?

Comment: Happy to hear. Can you close this question and post the second part as a new question? Otherwise the answer may be too long. Also it has do more with python than pyspark. So you will get better answers from python experts.

Comment: Ok I will post a second question about the list creation. I doubt its more of a python question than a spark question, because the collection of values from a spark df its done with spark sql functions. However, the part of if else statements is more of a python development.

Comment: I am making a minor edit to the title to better reflect the question-, hope thats ok